# What is the length and breadth of ONLY the screen in the Nexus 7?

Tags: screen, nexus-7

I'm not asking the diagonal values, but the length and breadth ones of the Nexus 7. And only of the LCD screen, not the entire hardware.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The screen size is 151mm * 94mm

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1760938

Answer (score 7):

You can always use some mathematics to obtain screen size:

```
X = sqrt ( Z^2 / (1 + (VR/HR)^2) )
```

where:

> sqrt = Square Root √‾‾‾
>
> X = screen width
>
> Z = diagonal screen size (7" for Nexus 7)
>
> VR = vertical resolution
>
> HR = horizontal resolution

which for Nexus 7, we have:

```
Z = 7"
VR = 1280
HR = 800
```

so:

> X = sqrt ( 49 / 3.56)
>
> X = 3.71 inches ~ **94mm**
>
> Y = (1280/800) * X = 1.6X
>
> Y = 5.936 inches ~ **151mm**

so we have **151mm x 94mm** which Peanut has linked to.

Comment: This assumes square pixels, which isn't always the case (though it is on the Nexus 7). You want to use the aspect ratio instead.

Comment: does this work for alternative pixel arrangements, like PenTile?

Comment: @derobert Thanks for the point, OK, so we can simply replace VR/HR with aspect ratio.

Comment: @LieRyan Yes, in the cases where pixels are not square, we can use aspect ratio (e.g 4:3 or 16:9) instead of actual resolution values (e.g 1280x800).

Answer (score 4):

***So you want to know the display area ..***

---

**(A.)** The non-masked (clear) area of the front face:

A simple metric ruler, and ASUS Nexus 7, gives you ..

Answer: **152mm x 95mm**

***OR***

**(B.)** The area of active pixels, on the *IPS* LCD display:

display pitch: **216 dpi** (*pixels per inch*, *leading edge to leading edge*)

pixel size: **96% of pitch** (*guesstimate, without engineering drawings*)

pixel geometry: **square** (*identical height, width*)

display size (in pixels): **1280 x 800**

screen area: (mathematical)

```
 => (height - 1) x pitch + pixel_width by (width - 1) x pitch + pixel_width
 => (1279 x 0.1175 + 0.1128) by (799 x 0.1175 + 0.1128)
 => 150.40 by 94.00 mm
```

Answer: **150.4mm x 94.0mm**

---

**ADDENDUM:**

Actual diagonal width, for **ASUS Nexus 7** display area:

```
  => square root ( height squared + width squared )
  => square root ( 150.40 squared + 94.00 squared )
  => square root ( 22,620.16 + 8,836 ) mm
  => 177.36 mm
  => 177.36 / 25.4 (convert to inches)
```

Answer: **177.4mm** or **6.98 in**

Answer (score 2):

try downloading the [Screeninfo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jotabout.screeninfo) app from the Google Play store for useful screen info.
This works on any other Android device as well.