# What are the non-diagonal screen dimensions of the Nexus 7?

Tags: nexus-7

Very simple question. I want to know the non-diagonal physical dimensions of the screen itself of a Nexus 7 (eg: 4" by 5" or whatever).

Every site I look it up on seems to just happily repeat that it's a 7" tablet with 1280x800px and so on.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://android.stackexchange.com/q/33994/12357

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are 3 7/16" x 5 15/16" by my measurements.

Comment: perfect, just what i wanted to know.